# How to find lines matching a pattern and delete them?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

In a file with lots of lines I want to delete lines that starts with `HERE IT IS`.

How can I do this using only command-line tools?

Comment: Although a little unconventional, you could use `vim` like so: `vim '+g/^HERE IT IS/d' +wq test.txt` ;)

Comment: @Doorknob, thank you for pointing this out. Actually I'm on my way to using vim

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try `sed`:

```
sed -i '/^HERE IT IS/d' <file>
```

**WARNING:** Its better to take a backup when using `-i` switch of `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '/^HERE IT IS/d' <file>
```

The original file will remain as `<file>.bak` and the modified file will be `<file>`.

Comment: How can I put newline character after matched string and write to newline ?

Comment: `sed -i 's/^HERE IT IS/HERE IT IS\n/' <file>`

Comment: Thank you very much for help, now will go read to tutorial. Seems like this is a great tool

Comment: @micgeronimo: happy to help. Check my edits please.

Comment: Very last question. Having this string 'HERE IT IS' and other text after it, how can I put `\n` after each line where 'HERE IT IS' found, not after above string but after the end of line where it was found

Comment: @micgeronimo try to ask the question you really want answered in your original question (remember you can edit it), rather than through comments that may get cleaned up / deleted. You can use `sed '/^HERE IT IS/G' file`.

Comment: Sed usage is so pro.

Answer (score 20):

In addition to the very good `grep` and `sed` answers you've received, here are some other tools that can do the same thing:

- A few Perl ways:

  ```
  perl -ne '/^HERE IT IS/ || print' file > newfile
  perl -ne 'print if !/^HERE IT IS/' file > newfile
  perl -ne 'print unless /^HERE IT IS/' file > newfile
  ```

  You can add the `-i` switch to any of the examples to edit the file in place:

  ```
  perl -i.bak -ne '/^HERE IT IS/ || print' file
  ```
- (g)awk

  ```
  awk '!/^HERE IT IS/' file > newfile
  ```

  Newer versions (4.1.1 and later) of GNU `awk` (the default `awk` on Linux) can also edit the file in place:

  ```
  gawk -i inplace  '!/^HERE IT IS/' file
  ```
- Shell (`bash`, `zsh`, `ksh`, probably others). This is kind of silly though, it *can* be done but other tools are better.

  ```
  while IFS= read -r line; do 
    [[ $line =~ ^"HERE IT IS" ]] || printf "%s\n" "$line"
  done < file > newfile
  ```

Comment: You're just showing off! ;-)  (but you got an upvote, because it's smart and I learnt a lot and the `bash` one made me LOL)

Comment: the bash one should use `printf "%s\n" "$line"` : quoting $line to preserve whitespaces, and avoiding some echo problems (interpreting special chars, etc). and avoids the need to add `--` too.

Comment: @OlivierDulac fair enough. I didn't want to complicate things for fringe cases but since Cuanglm has added `IFS=` and `-r`, I may as well go all the way and make it robust.

Comment: @terdon : it s all for the better good ^^ (and I did +1 already, though, as it's very informative for beginners)

Comment: @OlivierDulac I can assure you that if I were posting on [unix.se] I'd have used printf, IFS=, -r and quoting :). I often simplify things for the AU audience who are often less comfortable with the command line.

Answer (score 13):

I would use `grep` to filter them out. For example :

```
grep -v "^HERE IT IS" infile > outfile
```

Then move outfile back to infile.

Comment: Clever thinking

Answer (score 5):

`sed` is definitely the way to go.

This slight modification of the command @heemayl gave you will delete the line whether the same case is used in the pattern or not, due to the I in the pattern reference.

```
sed -i '/HERE IT IS/Id' <file>
```

If you had several files in a directory that you wanted to do this on, you could combine it with find like so.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec sed -i.bak '/HERE IT IS/Id' {} +
```

The maxdepth option means this won't recurse into directories.

Answer (score 4):

**Grep**

```
grep -P '^(?!HERE IT IS)' file
```

`(?!HERE IT IS)` negative lookahead assertion which makes the regex engine to match all the line starting boundary (*which is usually matched by `^`*) only if it's not followed by the string `HERE IT IS`

**python**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
fil = sys.argv[1]
with open(fil) as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('HERE IT IS'):
            print(line, end="")
```

Save the script in a file, say `script.py` and then run it through the below command on the terminal.

```
python3 script.py infile
```

Comment: you could use regex there, like `[print(l, end = "") for l in open(fil).readlines() if not re.match("HERE IT IS", l)]`, but it's not much more efficient than `startswith`. I wondered how `[print(l, end = "") for l in open(f).readlines() if not l.startswith("HERE IT IS")]` won't produce the output in a list.

Comment: The first time I ran into it, it looked strange to me to. It generates a print command (or whatever action you'd like to to with it) for all items in the defined list.

Comment: Undeleting it, just for fun :)

Answer (score 4):

Another python option:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
[print(l, end = "") for l in open(f).readlines() if not l.startswith("HERE IT IS")]
```

Where f is the path to the file, between quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc 'g/^HERE IT IS/d' -cx file
```

1. `g` global search
2. `d` delete
3. `x` save and close