# How to check for a matching pattern in bash?

Tags: bash, regex

I have a file in which value starts with ABC or ABD.

After fetching the value from input file how to check it starts with ABC or ABD?

eg:

```
value=$(cat file | awk 'NF{print;exit}' | awk '{print $1}')
```

and now I want to check this $value is starting with ABC or ABD . how?

Comment: How are you fetching it? In a character array?

Comment: No. value=$(cat file | awk 'NF{print;exit}' | awk '{print $1}') and now I want to check this $value is starting with ABC or ABD

Comment: Please update your question accordingly with these details.

Comment: Why check it in `bash`? why not check it in `awk`, since you're already using that?

Comment: There are several ways to do anything. `grep` is often used for pattern matching. see `man grep` Related:https://askubuntu.com/questions/587264/how-to-find-lines-matching-a-pattern-and-delete-them

Comment: FYI there's no need to use `cat`, and there's no need to use `awk` *twice*: your command can be reduced to `awk 'NF {print $1; exit}' file`

Comment: I have to fetch value from a file that s why cat. Yea, awk oen is true..Thank you..

Answer (score 7):

#### Using `case`

To check if a shell variable starts with ABC or ABD, a traditional (and very portable) method is to use a case statement:

```
case "$value" in
  AB[CD]*) echo yes;;
   *)      echo no;;
esac
```

Because this requires no external processes, it should be fast.

#### Using `[`

Alternatively, one can use a *test* command:

```
if [ "${value#AB[CD]}" != "$value" ]
then
   echo yes
else
   echo no
fi
```

This is also quite portable.

#### Using `[[`

Lastly, one can use the more modern and less portable *test* command:

```
if [[ $value == AB[CD]* ]]
then
   echo yes
else
   echo no
fi
```

#### Reading the file and testing all in one step

To read the first nonempty line of a file and test if its first field start with ABC or ABD:

```
awk 'NF{if ($1~/^AB[CD]/) print "yes"; else print "no";exit}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 echo $value | grep -c "^AB[CD]"
```

This will return 1 if the pattern is present at the beginning.