# Remove lines starting with "string1" and NOT containing "string2" with sed

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I would like to delete some lines in a file with more than 100K lines of data.

I only want to delete line which started with `MX` and NOT containing the word `sum`. How can I do that with `sed`?

Original file content:

[image: Original file content]

Expected file content:

[image: Expected file content]

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. I would like to cut'n'paste the input text to develop a solution, but I can't.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the examples, provided in the article [`sed` - 25 examples to delete a line or pattern in a file](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/sed-25-examples-to-delete-line-or.html) we can compose this command:

```bsh
sed '/^MX/{/sum/!d}' in-file            # just output the result
sed '/^MX/{/sum/!d}' in-file -i.bak     # change the file and create a backup copy
sed '/^MX/{/sum/!d}' in-file > out-file # create a new file with different name/path
```

Here is `perl` solution - [the source](https://askubuntu.com/a/587391/566421):

```bsh
perl -ne '/^MX((?!sum).)*$/ || print' in-file
perl -ne '/^MX((?!sum).)*$/ || print' in-file > out-file
```

The same regular expression will work with `grep -P` (more [explanations](https://askubuntu.com/a/968035/566421)). But, instead of the above construction that literally means *if not then print*, to preserve the output of the matched lines with `grep` we need the `-v` option:

```bsh
grep -vP '^MX((?!sum).)*$' in-file
grep -vP '^MX((?!sum).)*$' in-file > out-file
```

Here is also `awk` solution:

```bsh
awk  '! /^MX/ || /sum/ {print}' in-file
awk  '! /^MX/ || /sum/ {print}' in-file > out-file
```

It is relatively easy to compose your regular expressions by online tools as [regextester.com](https://www.regextester.com/15).

Productivity comparison:

```bsh
$ du -sh in-file
2.4M    in-file
$ TIMEFORMAT=%R

$ time grep -vP '^MX((?!sum).)*$' in-file > out-file
0.049
$ time sed '/^MX/{/sum/!d}' in-file > out-file
0.087
$ time awk  '! /^MX/ || /sum/ {print}' in-file > out-file
0.090
$ time perl -ne '/^MX((?!sum).)*$/ || print' in-file > out-file
0.099
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. However, I just realized that I have some lines with:


sum, sum@1, sum@2, sum@3 and I would like to keep all these line. What's should I do with your recomended soluiton?

Comment: Hi, @Kevin5059, you do not need nothing additional, all lines that contains "sum" should be kept.